# List of wifi-devices that are able to serve ad-hoc and access point simultaneously

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, wifi-driver

I would like to create a client wlan (infrastructure mode) and connect to an ad-hoc network at the same time with only one wifi adapter.

Most adapters in laptops and usb-sticks cannot serve both at the same time even if they are multi-ssid capable.

Is there a list of wireless-controllers that are able to serve ad-hoc and client network at the same time?

Comment: It may help if you specify your OS.

Comment: This is about the capability of the cards.

Comment: It's about the capability of the *drivers* for the cards (including the microcode that the drivers send to the card when initializing the card at powerup), which vary by OS. And possibly some OS-level APIs.